# New binomial coefficient identity?

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Is the following identity known?

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}\binom{2k}{k}=
\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

I have not found it in the following book:

- Henry Wadsworth Gould, [Combinatorial identities: a standardized set of tables listing 500 binomial coefficient summations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Combinatorial_identities.html?id=idI-AAAAIAAJ), Morgantown, West Virginia, 1972.

Comment: It may appear in a different form. E.g., notice that $\binom{n+k}{n-k}\binom{2k}{k}=\binom{n+k}{n}\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: known or not, Mathematica immediately evaluates it: [link to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(-1)%5Ek*Binomial%5Bn+%2B+k,+n+-+k%5D*Binomial%5B2*k,+k%5D%2F(2*k+%2B+1),+%7Bk,+0,++++n%7D%5D)

Comment: Can it be interpreted as an expected value?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In terms of hypergeometric series, the sum is $_3F_2(-n, 1+n, 1/2;1,3/2;1)$ and the identity is a special case of [Saalschütz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Saalsch%C3%BCtz's_theorem) (also called the Pfaff-Saalschütz theorem), one of the standard hypergeometric series identities.

A more general identity, also a special case of Saalschütz's theorem, is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{a}{a+k}\binom{n+k+b}{n-k}\binom{2k+b}{k}
  = \binom{n+b-a}{n}\biggm/\binom{n+a}{n}.$$
The O.P.'s identity is the case $a=1/2, b=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I obtained the identity from the Clausen’s identity for the Legendre polynomials. A generalization to the associated  Legendre functions produces $$\sum\limits_{k=m}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-m}}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}{n-k}\binom{2k}{k-m}=\frac{1}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: This identity also follows from the Saalschütz theorem (not immediately, but after some algebra) for the case $a=m+1/2$, $b=m+n+1$, $c=m+3/2$, because the sum now is $$\frac{\binom{n+m}{n-m}}{2m+1} {_3F_2}(m+1/2,m+n+1,-(n-m);m+3/2,2m+1;1).$$

Answer (score 7):

Use $\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}k$ in the sum. Define the functions
$$F(n,k)=(-1)^k\frac{2n+1}{2k+1}\binom{n+k}k\binom{n}{k}, \qquad
G(n,k)=2\cdot(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+k}{k-1}\binom{n}{k-1}.$$
Then $F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$. Sum over all integers $k$ to obtain $$f(n+1)-f(n)=0$$ where $f(n)=\sum_kF(n,k)$ is your sum. Since $f(0)=1$, the identity follows.

This method is called the Wilf-Zeilberger technique of summation routine.